# Filter Mail on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, email

I have a friend on FB who sends out FB mail for way too much stuff. Without removing her as a friend, is there any way to control the mail I get from this person? Unfortunately they are NOT using event invites.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a rule in my email program to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to stop receiving messages from this person altogether? You could put them on a list and block that list from sending messages.

I'm pretty sure that you can do this, but I don't have a facebook anymore so I can't check.

Comment: Yes, you can make lists and block the lists from having access to posting / sending you things, while still allowing them to be friends and see your info.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to sign up for the new [Facebook Messages](http://www.facebook.com/about/messages/) or wait for it to roll out.

The new platform allows for filtering so that only messages from friends important to you take priority. Everything else is sent to a folder called "other" (or you can manually move it across using the Actions menu which has a "Move to Other" option).

You can even remove yourself from large party/group conversations.

Answer (score -1):

From facebook

> **How do I stop receiving emails each
>   time someone sends a new message?**
>
> To stop receiving email notifications
>   about new messages, go to the
>   Notifications tab of your Account
>   Settings page.
>
> To stop receiving email notifications
>   about new messages from your group
>   conversations, simply leave that
>   conversation.

Comment: While this might help it doesn't solve the problem as it doesn't stop the actual message from being received.